# When Use WIN32_TempretureProbe My Retrieved value is Null?

Tags: wmi, wmi-query

I'm using wmi objecrs in c# language.How can I get CPU Temp ? My Code :

My Select query return null value and foreach is not working because my searcher object is null.

try
        {
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
                new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\CIMV2",
                "SELECT * FROM Win32_TemperatureProbe");

```
        foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("Win32_TemperatureProbe instance");
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("CurrentReading: {0}", queryObj["CurrentReading"]);
        }
    }
    catch (ManagementException)
    {

    }
```

Please give me clarification code. I'm search in google,bing but I can't find any good code.
I use MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature but I got error.

Best Regards

Answer (score 2):

`CurrentReading` is not implemented in the current release.

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394493%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Most of the information that the `Win32_TemperatureProbe` WMI class provides comes from SMBIOS. Real-time readings for the `CurrentReading` property cannot be extracted from SMBIOS tables. For this reason, current implementations of WMI do not populate the `CurrentReading` property. The `CurrentReading` property's presence is reserved for future use.

Comment: Why Win32_Fan return null value ?

Comment: You should check your WMI repository and see if it is corrupt. I can see the output when I create an instance of Win32_Fan. In any case, Win32_Fan is not related to your original question. Please mark if I have answered your initial question.